# Open a phpExcel file when genereted

Tags: php, phpexcel

This code is creates a xlsx file :

```
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```

I would like to allow visitors to visit and get the file in choosing "open or save"

Do you know how can I get this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the examples such as `01simple-download-xlsx.php` to see how it sends headers to the browser? And how it saves to `php://output`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code from `01simple-download-xlsx.php` in the `/Examples` folder shows how to do this:

```
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

$objWriter->save('Template.xls');

header('location:Template.xls');
```